# UItableViewCell order

Tags: uitableview

I'm very new to objective c and I would like to know how can I change the order of my data in my UITableviewCell, so that I have always the newest data in cell at the top of of the UITableView and not at the bottom, like it happens now ?

Comment: From where you are fetching the data? From a local array list? or from web responce?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some code and what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the order...just fill your array as such that it will have always the latest data at their staring index!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder your data source (most likely a NSArray), and then call

`[tableView reloadData];`

and the tableView will iterate over the data source again, and display the cells in the order the array is.